# Angular 4 aot environment

Tags: angular, aot

Is there a way to set the environment  when using ngc for aot compilation?
Like you do with ng build?

I followed the guide @ https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler but there's no mentioning of environments.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `dotenv` for setting environment variables: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Create a `.env` file with your environment-specific values

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

Then boostrap the .env file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

To read the values within code, use `process.env`:

```
var db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```

As per recommended best-practice, do not check in your `.env` file to source-control.

If you are using `webpack`, use `dotenv-webpack`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack